# Using Pugjs, what's the proper way to include a mixin within a links href attribute?

Tags: javascript, templates, pug

**tl;dr: What's the proper way to insert a mixin within a links href attribute?**

---

I'm starting to use Pug but I ran into an issue when I tried to use a mixin to generate an attributes value. Within my template I need to use a shortcode from a third-party website to include the phone number (and other settings) dynamically; which I've created a simple mixin to generate:

```
//- mixins.pug

mixin setting(value)
    | [setting:#{value}]
```

---

Within my header.pug template I am trying to code a default link for the phone number, which I'm inserting within the right-widget block; using a three-column header. The shortcode that the mixin generates, when processed by the third party server, grabs the phone number from their database.

```
//- header.pug

block right-widget
    h3.title
        | Call:
        a(href='tel:' +setting('Company Phone'))
            +setting('Company Phone')
    +button_reserve
```

When I try and include the setting mixin so it creates the shortcode for the phone number, it ends up being inserted as a string. Here is an example of the generated HTML:

```
<h3 class="title">
    Call: <a href="tel:" settings('Company="settings('Company" Phone')="Phone')">companyPhone</a>
</h3>
```

Instead of the desired result:

```
<h3 class="title">
    Call: <a href="tel:[setting:Company Phone]">[setting:Company Phone]</a>
</h3>
```

---

A solution I tried was using unbuffered code to include the mixin like so:

```
//- header.pug

block right-widget
    - var phone = +setting('Company Phone')
    h3.title
        | Call:
        a(href='tel:' + phone)
            phone
    +button_reserve
```

But when I do this, I get an error saying that setting (the mixin) is not a function. I also tried it without var as well, just to see what would happen. When searching, I see nothing discussing this. The solutions I tried were from this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41415049/use-pug-mixin-result-as-attribute-value/41487038). Both of the single line & multi line solutions must be outdated, because they did not work for me.

What's the best way to go about setting this up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mixins are meant to be used at the tag level. A simple **mixin** for your `a` tag could be:

```
mixin setting(value)
  a(href= 'tel:[setting:' + value + ']')= '[setting:' + value + ']'
```

You can also use **javascript functions** to do things like string manipulation:

```
- let settingString = (value) => { return '[setting:' + value + ']'}
```

Combining them can be powerful, and is likely what you're looking for:

```
// function
- let settingString = (value) => { return '[setting:' + value + ']'}

// mixin (that uses the function)
mixin settingLink(value)
  a(href= 'tel:' + settingString(value))= settingString(value)

// mixin call
h3.title
  | Call: 
  +settingLink('Company Phone')
```

This renders:

```
<h3 class="title">
  Call: <a href="tel:[setting:Company Phone]">[setting:Company Phone]</a>
</h3>
```

Comment: Thanks for responding Sean, I really appreciate it. So would you recommend setting up all ~20 shortcodes like this within a single file and just including the functions anytime they need to be used instead of using the mixins since some need to be used within attributes? Something like third-party-shortcodes.pug with what you mentioned above? Maybe defining a class with them all would be better? Would both of these be ideal to use when working with Pug/js?

Comment: Can you expand your question with the full range of "shortcodes" and how you're wanting to use them? There may be a more efficient way to do it but it's hard to tell from the limited example

Comment: Sure thing. So, `[setting:Company Phone]` is just one of the shortcodes I will be inserting somewhere within the pug templates for this project. There are also quite a few other ones, like `[social media]`, `[recaptchajs]`, `[image]`, `[text]`, `[video]`, etc. Most of these shortcodes also have their own attributes that can be set, somewhat like an HTML element has attributes.

Comment: So an example for the image shortcode would look something like `[image:!{className}?d=!{defaultUrl}&w=!{width}&h=!{height}]` The video shortcode has similar attributes as well as some of the other ones. While some of these generate their own HTML when loaded on the third-party platform, some of them are meant to be used within HTML attributes (like class, href, etc.) Would it be best to re-organize these as functions, instead of mixins, contained within a pug template file and just include them when I need to use them, or is there a better way to set these up for use within Pug?

Comment: If that doesn't make sense then let me know and I'll make a new question and link it, thanks for helping.

Comment: A new question with a link would be helpful. It's hard to tell what are meant to be parameters and what will static text within the rendered shortcode.